# Solving the Legendre symbol of -3 over p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to get a generalised result for $\left(\dfrac{-3}{p}\right)$

This equals $1$ if $p \equiv 1$ or $7 \pmod {12}$ and it equals $-1$ if $p \equiv -1$ or $5 \pmod {12}$.

Now this is fine, but the question asks for it to be simplified to a condition modulo $3$

Take the first claim first $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $p \equiv 7 \pmod 3$ and $p \equiv 7 \pmod 4$, now since $7 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ we have that $(-3/p) = 1 \iff p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and ($p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ or $p \equiv 7 \pmod 4$. I don't understand why this is apparently just a condition modulo $3$ and not a condition modulo $3$ and a condition modulo $4$

Comment: You have always $$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)$$ so you can study just when $3$ is a quadratic residue modulo p.

Comment: Try to prove that $3$ is quadratic residue for primes of the form $12\pm1$.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727879/computing-the-legendre-symbol-of-3-frac-3p?rq=1).